# Как вывести данные нужной даты?

Tags: php, sql

Привет всем. Подскажите, как вывести записи с указанным промежутком времени? Сейчас вообще ничего не работает.
В БД время записи записывается 2015-06-14

```
<form action='index.php' method='POST' id='myform'>
 <header>Найти запись с <input type='date' name='from' value=''/> 
 по <input type='date' name='to' value='' />
 <button class='btn mini green-stripe' name='show' value=''>Готово</button>
 </header>
</form>
    if (isset($_POST['show'])){
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $from1 = date('Y-d-m', strtotime($from));
    $to1 = date('Y-d-m', strtotime($to));
$query  = ("SELECT * FROM Configuration WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '".$from1."' and '".$to1."' ");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());   
}
```

+ Как сделать так, чтобы, если во втором поле не была выбрана дата, то искать записи с даты, которая выбрана в 1 поле иначе сообщить об ошибке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поле Date в БД имеет формат строка? Если да, то срочно изменяйте на DATE, либо INT и записывайте туде Timestamp, иначе вырастет много проблем.

> - Как сделать так, чтобы, если во втором поле не была выбрана дата, то искать записи с даты, которая выбрана в 1 поле иначе сообщить об ошибке?

```
if ($to) {
    SQL-запрос с BETWEEN
} else {
    SQL-запрос WHERE `Date` > from
}
```

**UPDATE**

Поле Date все-таки имеет формат Date, поэтому нужно всего лишь:

```
"SELECT * FROM Configuration WHERE `Date` BETWEEN CAST('".$from1."' AS DATE) and CAST('".$to1."' AS DATE) "
```

Comment: Поле Date имеет формат Date. Как правильно преобразовать  не пойму

Comment: Тогда извиняюсь. Нужно сделать CAST('2014-02-01' AS DATE)

Comment: Всё, проблема решена!